# Inside the world of JavaScript, is protocol just something larger than an interface?

Tags: javascript, interface, protocols

In the [MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator):

> The Generator object is returned by a generator function and it conforms to both the iterable protocol and the iterator protocol.

The iterable protocol has to do with having a object property `Symbol.iterator`, that is, if `obj` is a generator object, then `obj[Symbol.iterator]` has to have a value: it should have a reference to "a zero arguments function that returns an object, conforming to the iterator protocol."  So we don't usually call this an interface.

The iterator protocol seems much simpler, it just have to have an interface `.next()` that returns a `{ value: ___, done: ___}` object.

So in the JavaScript world, is protocol just a larger set of interface?  Interface means the "messages" that can be sent to an object (or the methods that can be invoked on an object), and a protocol is some requirements together with an interface?

Comment: I'd say yes, but that's not specific to JS. That's what the term *protocol* means in general.

Comment: because if not limited to JavaScript, then there might be discussion about Java and Objective-C's protocol vs interface

Answer (score 2):

In general, a [protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol) is the combination of an interface (method signatures) together with instructions of how it is used, e.g. the order of steps in which some methods are called.

In JS, neither "protocol" nor "interface" are constructs built into the language, so there are no precise definition.

Answer (score 1):

The [specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-generator-objects) says:

> A Generator object is an instance of a generator function and conforms to both the Iterator and Iterable **interfaces**.

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

There is no such thing as a "protocol". That's just a term used by MDN.

Comment: usually, I don't see an interface as described by a property and value, like `obj[Symbol.iterator]`... if it is the SmallTalk world where OOP came from, then it is "messages" that can be sent to objects... not like a property/value thing... but should be more like `getGeneratorFn()`